# Why isn't this a counterexample to Local Kronecker-Weber?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The local form of Kronecker-Weber tells me that every finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n)$ for some $n,$ where $\zeta_n^n =1.$

But what if $p$ is odd, and I have the finite abelian extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})$? Which $n$ could possibly work, seeing as this extension is ramified at $p$ but all these root of unity extensions are unramified?

Comment: For odd $p$, the Gauss sum $G_p = \sum_{a=1}^{p-1} (\frac{a}{p})\zeta_p^a$ satisfies $G_p^2 = (\frac{-1}{p})p = \pm p$, so $G_p = \pm\sqrt{p}$ or $\pm i\sqrt{p}$. Therefore $\sqrt{p}$ is contained in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and it is contained in $\mathbf Q(i,\zeta_p) = \mathbf Q(\zeta_{4p})$ if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. That shows how the number field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{p})$ lies in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf Q$, and in the same way $F(\sqrt{p})$ lies in a cyclotomic extension of $F$ for each field $F$ of characteristic $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $p$-th root of unity extension (more generally, $p^k$-th root of unity) is ramified over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Ah, I was being silly. Thanks; I will accept this in a few minutes [the website says I cannot accept an answer until the question is at least such and such age].

Comment: @user951252, it's a reasonable reflexive question to ask, though. :)